# How to use for loop to get 'SET' variable by batch file?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I try to use "set" and for-loop to get value by batch command.

```
set A=123,456

@for /f "delims=," %%i in ("%A%") do (
    echo %%i

)
```

I expect the result shall be following.

```
123
456
```

But it only show 123.  :(

Is there possible to use for loop to get 'SET' variable by batch file?

P.S I have been looking this issue in stackoverflow and there is no similar question.
If there are duplicate question please let me know thanks!!^^

Comment: You seem to misinterpret the `for /F` loop: it is capable of splitting a line of text into multiple tokens, but these are not iterated through, the tokens are returned in the same iteration, but by multiple loop variables (`%%i`, `%%j`, etc.), depending on the provided option string; refer to [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) for details...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
@echo off
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set a=123,456,789
:a
for /f "delims=," %%i in ("%a%") do (
  echo %%i
  set a=!a:%%i=!
  goto a
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a simple `for`

```
for %%i in (%A%) do echo %%i
```

Comment: This is what worked for me as well which I was going to submit

Comment: thanks for response,
i want "123" and "456"  not "123,456".

Comment: That's exactly what you'll get if you cut-and-paste the code I posted in place of your `for` statement.